# Zipping 2 files into a single folder in unix

Tags: linux, unix

My requirement is to send attachment in mail from unix.

There are many attachments, So I need to zip all files into a single folder.

So far I tried:

```
gzip -c abc.txt > xyz.gz
gzip -c cde.txt >> xyz.gz
```

But it is behaving like this:

```
cat abc.txt cde.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command.

gzip -c abc.txt cde.txt > xyz.gz

If you want more information about the gzip see the man page for the gzip.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this would be to bundle the files into a .tar file, then gzip it. This can be done by the `tar` command alone:

```
tar -cvzf xyz.tar.gz abc.txt cde.txt
```

The `-z` flag tells `tar` to gzip it's output.